# I have to create (central authority) unit like RSU and CARS in veins example

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I have to create (central authority) unit like RSU and CARS in veins example. how to create it. in which file what should i have to change. [i have added this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYUYk.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH0fe.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHdEk.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2H5A.png)

i have done all in which central authority has been created but when i tried to pass message from car to rsu and rsu to CA it didn't work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your CA as if it were an RSU and send messages normally. Don't forget to use the `populateWSM(destinationAddress)` method and fill in the other fields before sending the message.

Ex:

```
    //from RSU to CA
    populateWSM(CA_ADDRESS);
    wsm->setOtherFields(data);

    //from CA to RSU
    populateWSM(RSU_ADDRESS);
    wsm->setOtherFields(data);
```